# Differences in execution between WebStorm and console

Tags: javascript, console, this, webstorm, global

When running this code in WebStorm

```
function sayNameForAll() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var person1 = {
  name: "Nick",
  sayName: sayNameForAll
};
var person2 = {
  name: "Greg",
  sayName: sayNameForAll
};

var name = "michael";

person1.sayName();
person2.sayName();

sayNameForAll();
```

It prints out the following

```
Nick
Greg
undefined
```

but when running it in the console it prints out

```
Nick
Greg
Michael
```

What causes this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the browser there is a `window` object to which all variables created by scripts are a property of, thus in the browser `this.name` is "actually" `window.name` since `this` is referring to the `window` in function scope.

Now WebStorm runs this code as if it were a NodeJS application, this is great since WebStorm doesn't need to run a browser in the background and can simply use any node interpreter in the `PATH` variable. NodeJS however has no `window` object to which all variables are a property of, so it can't find `this.name`. `this` refers to the module which is empty since you are not inside of a module.

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm runs code in nodejs. Global context (this) refers to module and is an empty object, so property "name" is undefined.

If you run this code in a browser, global context (which is equal to window in this case) and global scope are somewhat mixed, because of legacy reasons.

Those are two different environments. You can add "use strict" at the beginning to make your code behave in more predictable way, but there still will be some differences.